# Base64 encoding of password string in python

Tags: python, password-protection

I came across following code to decode a password string, for example my password string is 'samplepassword', i can encode this using base64 algorithm and i got the below encoded value. I just used https://io/Utils/Base64/ to find encoded value.
"c2FtcGxlcGFzc3dvcmQ="

Below code hides the exact password of mine which is 'samplepassword', but anyone using the encodedvalue can easily find the original password using the same https://io/Utils/Base64/.

I'm confused in understanding what security base64 module providing, and Please suggest some best practices to hide the password in the python code.

```
def decode(encoded_value):
    try:
        import base64
        try:
            decoded_value = base64.b64decode(encoded_value).decode('ascii')
            return decoded_value
        except TypeError as e:
            raise TypeError("Attempted to decode {value} once. Illegal Value. ".format(value=encoded_value))
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError("Base64 import failed")
print(decode('c2FtcGxlcGFzc3dvcmQ='))
```

Comment: Q: I'm confused in understanding what security base64 module providing, A: *NONE WHATSOEVER!!!*  Base64 is an "encoding".  It is *NOT* encryption; it does *NOT* provide any "security".  The purpose of Base64 is to encode binary data into a text format (eg. for SMTP email attachments).

Comment: Base64 is a useful way to encode binary data as text data for transport.

Comment: Base 64 encoding does **NOT** provide security, it is not encryption.  It does allow a simple method of sanitization.

Comment: And don't put passwords in code, encrypted or otherwise.

Comment: @paulsm4 - Thanks for your answer. Now i understood i have to use encryption mechanism to secure my password not the encoding. Can you please suggest any module in python for doing the same.